# Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.shared:file-management:pom:3.0.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

Tags: maven

I am getting this error when creating a Maven or Gradle project without any dependencies.

> org.apache.maven.shared:file-management:pom:3.0.0 failed to transfer
> from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous   attempt.
> This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not
> reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or
> updates are forced.
>
> Original error: Could not transfer artifact
> org.apache.maven.shared:file-management:pom:3.0.0
> from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable
> to find valid certification path to requested target

Pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Which Java versions do you use? Which Maven version?

Comment: Thanks for replying khmarbaise                                                                            
Apache Maven 3.3.3 
Maven home: D:\apache-maven-3.3.3
Java version: 1.8.0_291, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre

Comment: First you should upgrade your Maven version and second your JDK version because there had been updates for TLS/SSL certificates.which might cause. this issue...

Comment: My corporate firewall is blocking the connection. Now it was fixed. Thanks for the suggestion.